# Console not reading input string correctly

Tags: c++, winapi, console, c++17

I tried to read a console input by executing C++-style

```
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    // also tested: std::cin >> str;
    return 0;
}
```

and C-style

```
int main()
{
    char* str = new char[20];
    scanf_s("%s", str);
    delete[] str;
    return 0;
}
```

But if I enter a string and press enter, the cursor in console won't jump to the next line, it jumps to the first column of the line where the entered command is located. A second key down on enter will cause an error:

**Error message box after executing C++-style code:**

> ```
> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: D:\_extern\Test\Test.exe
> File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\read.cpp
> Line: 259
>
> Expression: static_cast<void const*>(source_buffer) == static_cast<void const*>(result_buffer)
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion
> failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
> ```

**Error after executing C-style code:**

> ```
> Exception triggered at 0x00007FF95C9398E9 (ucrtbased.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation when writing at position 0x0000019155DF1000.
> ```

What could be the problem?

Comment: There is some code executed before. But this only prints lines by using std::cout. I won't post the whole project, it's a tcp socket project.

Comment: Which of those programs generates the error you quoted?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The C-style function.

Comment: 1) "_There is some code executed before. But this only prints lines by using std::cout._" Please provide [mcve], that reproduces your issue. If such "some code" invokes undefined behavior: it could explain such behavior. 2) Did you read the documentation of [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)? "_Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []._"

Comment: `scanf_s` [needs an explicit buffer size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I tried these methods above and commented out any console operations before. So my example above is the code concerning the console to be executed.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in the C-style code you don't need `new[]` and `delete[]`. Just define `str` as `char str[20];`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Uh, you're right, thanks!

Comment: It's crazy but after playing aroung with ´scanf_s()´ and ´scanf()´ there are no errors anymore but the problem that the cursor jumps to the first column of the line and a second key down on enter is required.

Answer (score 4):

You're not calling `scanf_s()` correctly, you're calling it as if it were ordinary `scanf()`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l):

> Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in `[]`. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable. For example, if you are reading a string, the buffer size for that string is passed as follows:
>
> ```
> char s[10];
> scanf_s("%9s", s, (unsigned)_countof(s)); // buffer size is 10, width specification is 9
> ```

So in your case, you need to write:

```
scanf_s("%s", str, 20);
```

Comment: Now, scanf_s works! Didn't see that. But when I press enter once, the cursor jumps to the first character in the same line again. I have to press it twice to get it work. Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you need to do that.

Comment: Are you running the program from the normal command prompt, or an IDE window? It sounds like an issue with your IDE (Visual Studio Code?)

Comment: I ran it using Visual Studio 2017 but I also tried to run it as external program.

Comment: Does it happen if you use ordinary `scanf()`? I can't test `scanf_s()` since it's Microsoft-specific and I don't have a Windows system.

Comment: It appears to cause the same issue although I used `scanf()`.

Comment: Cursor movement is not something you can control with stdio. I have no idea how to fix the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Well, I got the reason of the problem as posted one answer below. But I think you couldn't help me since you don't use Windows.